# Integrating lightadmin into wildfly

Tags: wildfly, lightadmin

I've been trying to get lightadmin up running with my wildfly 8.1 setup.
I've got a wildfly 8.1 running with entities which i would like to display in a UI. I've got no UI/web in the wildfly prior to trying to integrate lightadmin.

Im using maven into which i've added the following sections (as shown in http://lightadmin.org/getting-started/)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <repository>
        <id>lightadmin-nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

My (new) web.xml (in my persistence.xml i've got )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:base-url</param-name>
    <param-value>/admin</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>light:administration:base-package</param-name>
    <param-value>dk.test.business.batchjobs</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My entity which i would like to display in the ui

```
package dk.test.entities.batchjobs;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOB_EXECUTION")
public class JobExecution {
....
}
```

My AdministrationConfiguration class

```
package dk.test.business.batchjobs;

import dk.test.entities.batchjobs.JobExecution;
class JobAdministration extends AdministrationConfiguration {
....
}
```

My (first) problem is that im unable to extend AdministrationConfiguration
and i cant figure out why ?!?

Any hints ??

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to extend AdministrationConfiguration"? Do you get a compiler error? Any details?

Comment: Looking at the lightadmin website, they're only talking about Spring (Boot), not Java EE application servers. What makes you think this would run on WildFly or any other app server?

Comment: I know that JEE is not mentioned on lightadmin's website but i still wanted to try since it seems the fastest and easiest way to get a view of your entities, almost without doing any ui yourself. 

You're supposed to extend AdministrationConfiguration but its simply unknown - unknown symbol.

Comment: What's the error? `unknown - unknown symbol` isn't very helpful. Do you have a stack trace or anything?

Comment: Its a compile error. The AdministrationConfiguration is unknown in classpath. I guess its a maven problem or maybe its just not suited for wildfly.

Comment: I've abandoned this framework since theres absolutely no activity on  forum and very few if anybody knows about it.
Just dont know how i close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the apache incubator project instead
[apache batchee](http://batchee.incubator.apache.org/)
Works like a charm - only needs a maven dependency and your up running